# How to get geodata from IP

Tags: geo-location

Using `Sitecore 10.1.0` with `Sitecore Commerce 10.1.0`

I would like to get the geodata (and later the postal code, lat, long from this) using the user's IP address.

Following the method from this article.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/sitecore-experience-platform/retrieve-geolocation-data.html

[image]

Here is my method:

[image]

1. The `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` dll is not used in this method
2. There is an error in the method `GetRequiredService`

So, is that document correct?
What should I change to make this method work.

Comment: I added Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection dll, and it is resolving fo me, follow this blog - https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2021/09/sitecore-geolocation-api.html